# ¿Como puedo obtener el valor mas alto ingresado en los inputs?

Tags: javascript, html, linux

Al ingresar 3 valores en los inputs quiero que al pulsar el botón Mayor me de el valor mas alto escrito en los inputs

```
      <input type="text" id="input1"/>
      <input type="text" id="input2"/>
      <input type="text" id="input3"/>
      <br>
      <br>

      <button type="button" class="es1"onclick="Suma()">Suma</button>

      <button type="button" class="es2"onclick="Mostrar()">Texto1</button>

      <button type="button" class="es2"onclick="Mayor()">Mayor</button>
```

Javascript, en el javascript he hecho la suma y la obtencion de los valores, pero no se como obtener el valor mas alto

```
function Mostrar(){

var valores=document.getElementsByTagName("input");
document.getElementById("Valor1").innerHTML= (valores[0].value);
document.getElementById("Valor2").innerHTML= (valores[1].value);
document.getElementById("Valor3").innerHTML= (valores[2].value);

}

function Suma(){

  var valors = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  var total = 0;

  for (var i=0; i<valors.length; i++){
    total+= Number(valors[i].value);
  }

  var mitjana = total/valors.length;

  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

}
```

Comment: Guardalos en una lista y obten el mayor con las funciones correspondientes.

Comment: Usa la función [Math.max()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar una condición para compararlo cada uno con los 2 valores restantes. La condición que de verdadero, te devolverá el valor más alto, así:

```
function Mayor(){

    var valors = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

      if(valors[0].value > valors[1].value && valors[0].value > valors[2].value){
        console.log("El número mayor es: " + valors[0].value)
      }

      if(valors[1].value > valors[0].value && valors[1].value > valors[2].value){
        console.log("El número mayor es: " + valors[1].value)
      }

      if(valors[2].value > valors[1].value && valors[2].value > valors[0].value){
        console.log("El número mayor es: " + valors[2].value)
      }

  }
```

Si tienes más preguntas no dudes en preguntar